# Comparing 2 dataframe columns to 2 numpy array values in the same row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe. It contains `df['article_id']` and `df['user_id']`.
I also have a numpy array(or a list. I figured np array would be faster for this). Which contains an article_id and a user_id.
The point is to compare the df with the np array so I can filter out duplicate entries. Both user_id and article_id need to be the same value. So the idea is:

```
if df['article_id'] == nparray[:,0] & df['user_id'] == nparray[:,1]:
    remove the row from the dataframe
```

Here's what the df & np.array/list look like(as of now there is only 1 user_id but there will be more later). So if the np.array contains the same values from the dataframe, the dataframe rows should be deleted.:

```
array([[1127087222,          1],
       [1202623831,          1],
       [1747352473,          1],
       [1748645480,          1],
       [1759957596,          1],
       [1811054956,          1]])

    user_id article_id  date_saved
0   1   2579244390  2019-05-09 10:46:23
1   1   2580336884  2019-05-09 10:46:22
2   1   1202623831  2019-05-09 10:46:20
3   1   2450784233  2019-01-11 12:36:44
4   1   1747352473  2019-01-03 21:38:34
```

Desired output:

```
    user_id article_id  date_saved
0   1   2579244390  2019-05-09 10:46:23
1   1   2580336884  2019-05-09 10:46:22
3   1   2450784233  2019-01-11 12:36:44
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you post a small sample of the dataframe, list and desired output?

Comment: @Vink I added some code snippets

Comment: @SomeName: check my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your clarification. You may achieve your desired output using `np.isin` and negate operator '~' as follows:

```
df[~np.isin(df[['user_id', 'article_id']], nparray)]

Out[17]:
   user_id  article_id           date_saved
0        1  2579244390  2019-05-09 10:46:23
1        1  2580336884  2019-05-09 10:46:22
3        1  2450784233  2019-01-11 12:36:44
```

Comment: They do not have the same shape. I added code snippet what they look like. Df has 2 more columns.